asp.net c# webform passing parameters to a python script not running
I found an example of how to pass parameters using PythonNet, but I am not able to get it to trigger my Python code.  Developing on VS 2022.  I'm wanting to (first) create a subdirectory if is doesn't already exist.  The path and directory should be passed from C#.
 protected void btnPythonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {        
     // full path of python interpreter 
     string python = @"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe";

     // python app to call 
     string myPythonApp = @"C:\OllamaDocs\MyTestPython.py";

     // Paramters to send to Python  (location of docs and Chroma for this user
     string OllamDocsPath = @"C:\OllamaDocs\100\1\";
     string OllamaChromaFilename = "Chroma_100_1B";
     
     try
     {
         System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo myProcessStart = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(python);
         myProcessStart.UseShellExecute = true;
         myProcessStart.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

         // pass arguments to python script
         myProcessStart.Arguments = myPythonApp + " " + OllamDocsPath + " " + OllamaChromaFilename;

         System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

         myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStart;

         myProcess.Start();

         lblStatus.Text = myPythonApp + " Created " + OllamDocsPath + OllamaChromaFilename;

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         errorMessage = ex.Message;
         lblStatus.Text = errorMessage;

     }

 }   // end PythonTest()

My Python test script is located in the root of C: as follows (MyTestPython.py)
import os import sys

# Test Phase II

#Get args from C# 
OllamaPath = sys.argv[0] 
OllamaChroma = sys.argv[1]
    
# Define the directory for vector store persistence
#persist_directory = "C:\\OllamaDocs\\100\\1\\chroma_db_100-1" 
persist_directory = OllamaPath

# Check if the vector store already exists 
if not os.path.exists(persist_directory):
    print("Creating new Chroma Directory " + persist_directory)
    os.makedirs(persist_directory) else:
    # Load the existing Chroma vector store
else:
# Load the existing Chroma vector store
print("path exists.")

